# Same Workbook Hyperlinks keep breaking - Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, broken-links

I have a workbook with a mass hyperlinks; all are referring to sheets in the same workbook but they keep breaking once I save the file and reopen it.

The workbook is on a server machine just in case if this info is relevant to the problem.

I know I could use the hyperlink formula but its not applicable in my case so what's causing the hyperlinks to break constantly ?

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Well I can't think of examples rather than posting a few image. I simply insert hyperlink on a cell and select a place in  the document then select the desired sheet and the cell is automatically referenced to cell A1 in the target sheet then the links work fine for the session but once the workbook is saved and reopened the link don't go to the target its just clicked and the color is changed from blue to purple. Meanwhile, I will try to illustrate with images if applicable. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What is the filetype? Sounds similar to what happens when you save a .csv rather than .xlsx.